# Evernote SDK: Authenticate to shared notebook

Tags: android, evernote

I'm trying to gain access to shared notebook using Evernote Android SDK. I'm receiving shareKey via REST api from server side of the applicaiton. I'm using the code below:

```
AuthenticationResult result = EvernoteSession.getInstance()
                    .getEvernoteClientFactory()
                    .getNoteStoreClient()
                    .authenticateToSharedNotebook(shareKey);
            String token = result.getAuthenticationToken();
            String sharedNotebookStoreUrl = result.getNoteStoreUrl();
            TBinaryProtocol sharedNoteProtocol = new TBinaryProtocol(
                    new THttpClient(sharedNotebookStoreUrl));
            NoteStore.Client sharedNoteStore = new NoteStore.Client(sharedNoteProtocol);
            SharedNotebook sharedNotebook = sharedNoteStore.getSharedNotebookByAuth(token);
```

But when I call

```
AuthenticationResult result = EvernoteSession.getInstance()
                        .getEvernoteClientFactory()
                        .getNoteStoreClient()
                        .authenticateToSharedNotebook(shareKey);
```

it trows an exception

```
EDAMNotFoundException(identifier:SharedNotebook.id, key:39116)
```

What I am doing wrong? How I can accept sharing and access to shared notebook's content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the wrong `sharedNotebookStoreUrl`.

A `SharedNotebook` is the record of a share of a `Notebook` N from account A to account B. It is stored in the `noteStoreUrl` of account A (notebook N). Account B will have a corresponding `LinkedNotebook` record that points to the SharedNotebook (not the notebook). The `LinkedNotebook` will be on account B.

```
NoteStoreUrl for account A            NoteStoreUrl for account B
Notebook N                            LinkedNotebook L (points to S)
SharedNotebook S (points to N)
```

Sounds like you're in account B and trying to access the Notebook N. What you want to do is fetch the noteStoreUrl from the LinkedNotebook L and then use that to call `authenticateToSharedNotebook`. You can fetch the LinkedNotebooks by calling [listLinkedNotebooks](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/NoteStore.html#Fn_NoteStore_listLinkedNotebooks).

Comment: When the account A creates SharedNotebook with accout B, account B won't have a corresponding LinkedNotebook until it accepts a share. How I can accept a share using Evernote SDK?

Comment: I don't think we expose that functionality to clients. You can only join a shared notebook if it's shared by work chat, or if the (joining) user clicks the link in the email that is sent as a result of the NoteStore#shareNotebook call.
EDIT doesn't look like the shareNotebook call is documented online - some of the SDKs may have it, depending on how up-to-date they are.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work in your exact scenario, but you can try the following to create the Linked Notebook in User B's account (I do something similar to this in a slightly different scenario):

```
LinkedNotebook linkedNotebook = new LinkedNotebook();
linkedNotebook.SharedNotebookGlobalId = <the shareKey you got from the server>
linkedNotebook.ShareName = <the name of the Shared Notebook>
linkedNotebook.Username = <the username of user A; i.e. the owner of the Shared Notebook>
linkedNotebook.ShardId = <the shardId of the notebook in user A's account>
LinkedNotebook createdLinkedNotebook = noteStore.createLinkedNotebook(authenticationToken, linkedNotebook);
```