# Evernote SDK Java: SHARD_UNAVAILABLE while authenticating to Shared Notebook

Tags: java, evernote

I am attempting to authenticate to Shared Notebook to extract Notes from it. But I am receiving EDAMSystemException with Error Code: "SHARD_UNAVAILABLE". While debugging it, I noticed that the ShardId of my account and the ShardId of the Shared Notebook is different. 
This never happened while Testing in the Sandbox Account(Currently Testing it in Production). Below is the code:

```
List<LinkedNotebook> linkedNotebooks = noteStore.listLinkedNotebook();
for(LinkedNotebook linkedNotebook: linkedNotebooks){
    String sharkey = linkedNotebook.getShareKey();
    String share_token = noteStore.authenticateToSharedNotebook(sharekey).getAuthenticationToken(); 
    System.out.println("Share Token:" +shareToken)
}
```

Would be great if anybody helps me out with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to authenticate to the shared notebook using a note store client object that is *specific to that linked notebook*, not the default one that you're using. A note store client "points" to a particular note store and can only access data on that store. All of a user's own personal data lives inside one note store, and that's the main note store client that you have created there as `noteStore`.

Accessing each linked notebook requires creating a new note store client object that is a "client" of the place where that linked notebook lives. There's enough information to do this inside the `LinkedNotebook` object you have there but there are a couple additional steps.

You may want to take a look at [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37122308/73297). You can use the information inside the LinkedNotebook object to create a new note store client that points to where the corresponding shared notebook lives. Then use *that* note store to authenticate to the shared notebook there. In short: you'll get the note store URL from the linked notebook record, then use that plus your existing auth token to create a new note store client to the shared notebook and authenticate to it.

Syntax (and complexity) may vary depending on your specific platform and SDK version. Maybe see also [this page](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/articles/notebook_sharing.php#) for some conceptual help.